# libgcj-java-placeholder.sh

Tags: java

i downloaded jdk 1.6 and placed in /usr/java. When tried giving java -version , the above script(libgcj-java-placeholder.sh) is getting invoked stating below lines

> ```
> This script is a placeholder for the /usr/bin/java and /usr/bin/javac
> master links required by jpackage.org conventions.  libgcj's
> rmiregistry, rmic and jar tools are now slave symlinks to these
> masters, and are managed by the alternatives(8) system.
>
> This change was necessary because the rmiregistry, rmic and jar tools
> installed by previous versions of libgcj conflicted with symlinks
> installed by jpackage.org JVM packages.
> ```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it ! 
The Symbolic link in /usr/bin was pointing to a wrong path.
Removed those link and created new links pointing to my java folder.

Commands used :

```
mv java java_old
mv javac javac_old
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java java
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/javac javac

java -version
```